# Android how to use WebTextView to overlay TextFields in Webview

Tags: android, instance, android-webview

I want to use WebTextView to overlay text fields in Webview so that I can save their state and restore them after orientation change.

I want to retain the text data in WebView after orientation change.

I could not find examples related to the [WebTextView](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/2.3/android/webkit/WebTextView.html) . Can anyone point me with an example to achieve the above ?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` as an attribute to the `<activity>` tag inside the manifest.xml

Comment: I need keyboard when the orientation changes, so it is not an option for me. thanks for the reply anyways.

Comment: do you use a hardware keyboard ?? if not, then this solution has nothing to do with the keyboard as far as i know... according to the documentation :"keyboardHidden" The keyboard accessibility has changed — for example, the user has revealed the hardware keyboard.

Comment: I've tested this on my SGS2 and it's working fine.... just try it on a real device and see what you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

There is no WebTextView in Android SDK, thats why you can't find any examples.